# Множественное число сказуемого?

Tags: сказуемые, единственное-множественное-число

Сохранение, возрождение и развитие народных художественных промыслов являе(ю)тся одной из задач госполитики в сфере культуры.

Answer (score 3):

**Сохранение, возрождение и развитие народных художественных промыслов являются одной из задач госполитики в сфере культуры.**

**При прямом порядке слов** (сказуемое следует за однородными подлежащими) обычно употребляется **форма множественного числа сказуемого.**

Розенталь: [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#з_08](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_08)

Сочетание "одной из задач" не оказывает существенного влияния на выбор числа, что видно **из следующих примеров:**

Считаем, что свобода слова в любом обществе и доступ к информации...**являются** одной из основополагающих ценностей демократического государства. Дипломатический вестник», 2004.05.25]

Прежде всего, человеческая мораль и совесть **существуют и являются** одной из мощных и вечных движущих сил истории. [ Библиотека «Огонек», 1989]

Comment: Обычно - да, но не категорично. По-моему, здесь как раз соответствует пункту 3 по Вашей ссылке: 3.      Форма единственного числа сказуемого предпочитается при смысловой близости однородных подлежащих, например:
2)      сказуемое следует за подлежащим: Неточность и запутанность выражений свидетельствует только о запутанности мыслей (Чернышевский); Эта простота и ясность мышления заключает в себе задатки новой жизни... (Добролюбов); Никто и ничто не нарушало тишины. Ср. также: выписка и выдача документов производится (общая операция) – прием и выдача книг производятся (разные операции).

Answer (score 2):

Я бы предпочла ед. число, потому что есть  указание на их общность - одна из задач. Всё это - одна задача, является задачей.

Сохранение, возрождение и развитие народных художественных промыслов является одной из задач госполитики в сфере культуры.

Comment: Думаю, оба варианта возможны, но интуитивно я бы предпочел ед. ч.